# What is the proper syntax to import view in urls.py in django3?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

What is the proper syntax to import view.py into urls.py

I am trying to add pagination and search and have run into a SyntaxError "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" .

I tried my best to debug it the last few days. I can see it is the way I am importing view. I tried a bunch of combinations and made it worse any guidance extremely appreciated.

File "C:\Users\taylo\Desktop\pybox\blogdemo\blog\urls.py", line 3

**blogdemo/blog/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views index, single, SearchResultsListView


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:id>/', views.single, name='single'),
    path('search/', SearchResultSingleView.as_view(), name='search_results'), #added
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**blogdemo/blogdemo/URLS.PY**

```
from .views index, single, SearchResultsListView
from django.conf import settings 
from django.conf.urls.static import static 
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include # imported include module

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('blog.urls')), #added
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('search/', SearchResultListView.as_view(), name='search_results'), #added
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**blogdemo/VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Article


def index(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(articles,3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    posts = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts': posts})

def single(request, id):
    single = Article.objects.get(id=id)
    nextpost = Article.objects.filter(id_gt=single.id).order_by('id').first()
    prevpost = Article.objects.filter(id_lt=single.id).order_by('id').last()
    return render(request, 'single.html', {"single": single, "prevpost": prevpost, "nextpost": nextpost})

class SearchResultsListView(SingleView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'article_list'
    template_name = 'templates/search_results.html'
```

**blogdemo/MODELS.PY**

```
from django.db import models


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bio = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField( max_length=50)     
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    offical = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    observed_fall = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    yearfound = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    mass = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    classification = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    descriptions = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    history = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    place_of_purchase = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    shock_stage = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    weathering_grade = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

ERRORS IN PROBLEMS SECTION
[image: 'ARTICLE HAS NOT OBJECT MEMBER']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
from .views import index, single, SearchResultsListView
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it sorry I don't have 15 points to up vote it as correct. I can't believe I missed that. Now I can try to figure out why only the pagination shows now non related.

Comment: @johntaylor, you now  have more than the 15 points :))

Comment: I sure do thanks for the reminder, almost a year later was posted on my b-day and I am currently finishing my last touch on Django project with machine learning for work.